# TableView showing wrong data after segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

This is a project is a simple car's dictionary, I am using core data, from a .csv file uploaded from a server.

When I select the word in the first tableview trigger a second page to read the definition in another tableview, there is the problem is always showing incorrect word and definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the section number in the index path you get from `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`.  For a sectioned table, you need to translate a section/row combination into a data reference.

A standard way of doing that is with an array of arrays (e.g. `dictionaryItems:[[Dictionary]]`).  That way, you can get an array of items by using the index path section on the outer array and the specific item by using the index path row on the array the section reference returns.

--- UPDATE with methods that need code changes in `DictionaryTableViewController`

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Assume a single section after a search
    return (searchController.active) ? 1 : sectionTitles.count
}


// Create a standard way to get a Dictionary from an index path
func itemForIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Dictionary? {
    var result: Dictionary? = nil

    if searchController.active {
        result = searchResults[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        let wordKey = sectionTitles[indexPath.section]
        if let items = cockpitDict[wordKey] {
            result = items[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
    return result
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DictionaryTableViewCell

    if let dictionary = itemForIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.wordLabel.text = dictionary.word
        cell.definitionSmallLabel.text = dictionary.definition
    } else {
        print("Cell error with path \(indexPath)")
    }

    return cell
}

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDictionaryDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! DictionaryDetailViewController
            if let dictionary = itemForIndexPath(indexPath) {
                destinationController.dictionary = dictionary
            } else {
                print("Segue error with path \(indexPath)")
            }
            searchController.active = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi do you know where can I find a tutorial or help on how to do this? :(

Comment: HI sorry for  the delay. this works great. I will follow step by step to try to learn for the next time, Thank you very much really help me :)

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and think the trouble is with `destinationController.dictionary = (searchController.active) ? searchResults[indexPath.row] : dictionaryItems[indexPath.row]`

you should get dictionary like this (as you did in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`):

```
    let dictionary = (searchController.active) ? searchResults[indexPath.row]: dictionaryItems[indexPath.row]
    let wordKey = sectionTitles[indexPath.section]
    let items = cockpitDict[wordKey]
```

Now `item` will be the dictionary to pass to detail view.

I got this idea, when I saw you are populating your data in table view very efficiently.

Comment: Good point.  After `createCockpitDict()` is called, `dictionaryItems` is only really useful for linear operations, like the filter.

Comment: @Jade  As he points out in his answer, you're **already** doing it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath `.

Comment: I added this and still does not work, if I add {return items.count} I get error (variable used within its own initial value)

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing with "return items.count".  We were talking about how to find the right thing to pass to `destinationController.dictionary`.

Comment: @Phillip Mills It was working well until I add the Index and sections Index, I am really confused how to do this, if you have time can you add some explanation direct in GitHub? I understand I am asking to much :(

Comment: Well, I could never have been as helpful as @PhillipMills. Still, you are welcome.